# fill-region fails as fill-forward-paragraph complains about argument type

Tags: python, fill-paragraph

I am trying to fill a region within a Python docstring. The function `find-docstring-limits` returns the limits of the docstring. Here is the function:

```lisp
(defun indent-docstring-paragraph ()
  "Indent the current paragraph within a Python docstring without exceeding its limits."
  (interactive)
  ;; Gets the docstring limits.
  (let* ((docstring-limits (find-docstring-limits))
         (docstring-start (car docstring-limits))
         (docstring-end (cadr docstring-limits))
         paragraph-start paragraph-end)
    ;; Ensures that the docstring limits are valid.
    (when docstring-limits
      (save-excursion
        ;; Finds the start of the current paragraph within the docstring.
        (goto-char (max (point) docstring-start))
        (while (and (> (point) docstring-start)
                    (not (looking-at-p "\\s-*$")))
          (forward-line -1))
        (unless (looking-at-p "\\s-*$")
          (forward-line 1))
        (setq paragraph-start (point))
        
        ;; Finds the end of the current paragraph within the docstring.
        (goto-char (min (point) docstring-end))
        (while (and (< (point) docstring-end)
                    (not (looking-at-p "\\s-*$")))
          (forward-line 1))
        (setq paragraph-end (point)))
      
      ;; Applies fill-region to the identified paragraph, without exceeding the docstring limits.
      (fill-region paragraph-start paragraph-end))))
```

It fails with error:

```
fill-forward-paragraph: Wrong type argument: arrayp, 189
```

The code does reach `fill-region`, and I thought `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-end` would be of the proper type. `189` is the value of `paragraph-start` when printed just before `fill-region` with `(message "%s" paragraph-start)`. Looking at the source code of `fill-region`, I do not see where it calls `fill-forward-paragraph` with another argument than `1` or `-1`. What could be happening?

### Update with debugger

I am trying again on an example with `189` as `paragraph-start`, and `227` as `paragraph-end`. If I call `(fill-region 189 227)` within the function (so substituting the expected values by hard-coded values), it fails as before. But if I call manually `(fill-region 189 227)` within the docstring in Python buffer, it works... Hence `fill-region` (or another function called by it) is not doing the same.

I tried to call `fill-region` in the buffer where the custom function `indent-docstring-paragraph` is defined, and it works. So it does not seem that `fill-region` was overwritten.

I got the suggestion to use the debugger, and here is what it says:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument arrayp 226)
* forward-paragraph(1)
* fill-forward-paragraph(1)
* #f(compiled-function (from to &optional justify nosqueeze to-eop) (interactive (progn (barf-if-buffer-read-only) (list (region-beginning) (region-end) (if current-prefix-arg (quote full))))) #<bytecode 0x1f6d9b>)(189 227)
* apply(#f(compiled-function (from to &optional justify nosqueeze to-eop) (interactive (progn (barf-if-buffer-read-only) (list (region-beginning) (region-end) (if current-prefix-arg (quote full))))) #<bytecode 0x1f6d9b>) (189 227))
* fill-region(189 227)
  (progn (save-excursion (goto-char (max (point) docstring-start)) (while (and (> (point) docstring-start) (not (looking-at-p "\\s-*$"))) (forward-line -1)) (if (looking-at-p "\\s-*$") nil (forward-line 1)) (setq paragraph-start (point)) (goto-char (min (point) docstring-end)) (while (and (< (point) docstring-end) (not (looking-at-p "\\s-*$"))) (forward-line 1)) (setq paragraph-end (point))) (message "%s & %s" paragraph-start paragraph-end) (fill-region 189 227))
  (if docstring-limits (progn (save-excursion (goto-char (max (point) docstring-start)) (while (and (> (point) docstring-start) (not (looking-at-p "\\s-*$"))) (forward-line -1)) (if (looking-at-p "\\s-*$") nil (forward-line 1)) (setq paragraph-start (point)) (goto-char (min (point) docstring-end)) (while (and (< (point) docstring-end) (not (looking-at-p "\\s-*$"))) (forward-line 1)) (setq paragraph-end (point))) (message "%s & %s" paragraph-start paragraph-end) (fill-region 189 227)))
  (let* ((docstring-limits (find-docstring-limits)) (docstring-start (car docstring-limits)) (docstring-end (car (cdr docstring-limits))) paragraph-start paragraph-end) (if docstring-limits (progn (save-excursion (goto-char (max (point) docstring-start)) (while (and (> (point) docstring-start) (not (looking-at-p "\\s-*$"))) (forward-line -1)) (if (looking-at-p "\\s-*$") nil (forward-line 1)) (setq paragraph-start (point)) (goto-char (min (point) docstring-end)) (while (and (< (point) docstring-end) (not (looking-at-p "\\s-*$"))) (forward-line 1)) (setq paragraph-end (point))) (message "%s & %s" paragraph-start paragraph-end) (fill-region 189 227))))
  indent-docstring-paragraph()
  eval((indent-docstring-paragraph) nil)
  eval-expression((indent-docstring-paragraph) nil nil 127)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression (indent-docstring-paragraph) nil nil 127)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression)
```

Comment: `fill-paragraph` (`M-q`) should already work if you are using triple (single/double) quotes for the docstring. If you are using single (double) quotes for the docstring then it does not work as they indicate single line comments in python (see e.g. [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/#multi-line-docstrings)). Does this 'solve' the issue?

Comment: This does explain why I get the error. I actually tried `fill-paragraph` but it fills beyond the triple quotes, so that the first line gets filled with the function header. Hence `fill-region` restricted to the paragraph identified by the function. Here, I focus on one part; but I wrote a broader function to fill Google-style docstrings. Ironically, I have only problems with the most simple part which is to fill the top paragraphs (before `Args:` and `Returns:`)...

Comment: If I understand correctly this is a custom function you're writing, in which case I think the best answer is to point you to `C-h i g (elisp)Debugging` so that you can learn how to use the debugging facilities.

Comment: What's the value of `paragraph-end` just before the call to `fill-region`. You can then run `M-: (fill-region 639 <whatever>)` and see whether it works. Running it in the debugger as @phils suggests is indeed the best way for you to understand and solve such problems.

Comment: Following the recommendations by @phils and @NickD, I edited the question with debug traces and also calling `fill-region` with the actual values directly.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, without fully understanding the reason.

I renamed `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-end` to `doctring-paragraph-start` and `docstring-paragraph-end`. Apparently, defining the variables `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-end` outside `fill-region` had consequences within `fill-region` or one of the functions it calls.

Comment: Ha.  Yes, see `C-h v paragraph-start` and `C-h v paragraph-end`.  If you're using dynamic variables, you need to avoid name clashes -- you should simply name-space every custom variable (and function) name with some reliably non-conflicting prefix so that it won't clash with other code.  I recommend using lexical-binding for your custom library, though, as that simplifies matters.

Comment: You can also largely get away with using single-word (i.e. no hyphens) names for dynamic let-bound variables -- if one of those isn't bound by default, there's a pretty strong chance it's not going to cause an issue for let-binding; so you can use your judgement there if for any reason you need to stick with dynamic binding for your code. Lexical binding is really the way to go, though.